# Do nothing on table row hover - How could I do this?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I have been trying to disable the row hover for [antd table](https://ant.design/components/table/) (for expandable rows) but no success. I want to disable the hover on all child rows.

Here is a simple table that I am generating using antd.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Table } from 'antd';

const columns = [
    {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
    }
];

const data = [
    {
        key: 1,
        name: 'John Brown sr.',
        age: 60,
        address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
        children: [
        {
            key: 11,
            name: 'John Brown',
        },
        {
            key: 12,
            name: 'John Brown jr.'
        },
        {
            key: 13,
            name: 'Jim Green sr.'
        },
        ],
    }
];



ReactDOM.render(
    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />,
    document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

Here is the [table fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-herschel-b2z46) that shows the table, that gets rendered. The CSS that I am trying to apply the change the hover is:

```
tr.ant-table-row.ant-table-row-level-1:hover {
   background: red;
}
```

But this does not work. I see a fluctuation of colors between red and blue. How could I do this?

What I mainly want is no hover effect. But I am unable to do this.

Comment: Please try `background: red !important;`

Comment: Have you trued applying the pointer events property to the table in CSS? table { pointer-events: none; }

Comment: If you don't want hover effect then why are you changing background color on hover?

Comment: @Xander Does not work

Comment: @adesurirey Does not work

Comment: @ravibagul91 `red` just allowed me to check if the css was working. But it does not.

Comment: I'm a bit confused but it sounds like the ant design is applying some css that @Amanda doesn't want. Is that correct @Amanda? You could try using !important with your css to ensure it takes effect instead of ant design styling.

Comment: None of these answers work anymore. The biggest flaw of Ant design is its dependency on CSS, it's anti-dynamic and nowadays, it's nothing but anti-productive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
.ant-table-tbody > tr.ant-table-row-level-1:hover > td {
  background: unset;
}
```

That's working on your fiddle.

(`background: unset` as suggested by @ravibagul91)

Comment: I only want to disable this for the child rows.

Comment: @Amanda what do you mean by child rows? Do you have expandable rows?

Comment: Yes, as given in my question and fiddle.

Comment: Worked, but I used `ant-table-row` instead of `ant-table-row-level-1`

Comment: Used `ant-table-row` also, antd 4.12.3, thanks @IslamMurtazaev

Answer (score 8):

This is the place you can change this effect,

```
.ant-table-thead>tr.ant-table-row-hover:not(.ant-table-expanded-row)>td, 
.ant-table-tbody>tr.ant-table-row-hover:not(.ant-table-expanded-row)>td, 
.ant-table-thead>tr:hover:not(.ant-table-expanded-row)>td, 
.ant-table-tbody>tr:hover:not(.ant-table-expanded-row)>td {
    background: unset; //Change the existing color to `unset`
}
```

Comment: This is the only that really worked to me

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answers did not work for me, if anyone else has this problem this is how I fixed it:

First, set the className property in the Table component to something, for e.g. 'time-table-row-select' like below:

```
<Table
    dataSource={data}
    columns={columns}
    className='time-table-row-select'
/>
```

Then add the following in CSS:

```
.time-table-row-select > .ant-spin-nested-loading > .ant-spin-container > div > .ant-table-content > .ant-table-body > table > tbody > tr:hover > td {
    background-color: unset;
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using the scroll parameter you need to use this:

```
.time-table-row-select > .ant-spin-nested-loading > .ant-spin-container > div > .ant-table-content > .ant-table-scroll > .ant-table-body > table > tbody > tr:hover > td {
    background-color: unset;
}
```

---

Since there appears to be additional caveats depending on how you are using the table, I'll go through my logic for how to figure out which class selector to use (as it seems like most people on web development stackoverflow do not do this & it's incredibly frustrating):

Find the location of the class you provided to the Table component, then append each subsequent child tag to your selector until you reach the tr tag that follows tbody, add :hover to it, then add > td to that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding other theme variables with Less, you can just add this line to the variables override file.

`@table-row-hover-bg: unset;`

You can also change *unset* to any other color you want to set there.

Answer (score 0):

This turned off the row highlight hover for me.

```
  .ant-table-tbody > tr.ant-table-row:hover > td {
      background: none !important;
  }
```